# My second website is displaying the default theme instead of my custom theme

Tags: theme

I am setting up a second website on my magento system.
Eventually this will have its own domain name and be hosted in my main magento installation.

To allow me some time to finalise the domain name and test some themes I would like to set up the new website under my "dev" magento as a SECOND WEBISTE. (ie run multiple websites with a common backend)

I have been reading various websites to get information and I have done the following.
1. Installed a new theme "diyalarms" (copied the current theme from my current website with a new name of "diyalarms" from origial theme files I purchased)

2. Created a new Website, Store, View with the code "diyalarms"
3. Under General/Web I - 1. Changed scope to diyalarms, 2. changed unsecure & secure urls to diyalarms.ozfitsports.com.au and unchecked use defaults.
4. In Cpanel created a new subdomain diyalarms.ozfitsports.com.au and pointed to /dev
5. Added the following to index.php

   ```
   switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

       case 'diyalarms.ozfitsports.com.au':

           $mageRunCode = 'diyalarms';

           $mageRunType = 'website';

       break;
   }
   ```
6. Under System/design created a Design for View "diyalarms" by selecting theme from dropdown box.

Typing in diyalarms.ozfitsports.com.au open with what appears to be the "default" magento theme, not the theme "diyalarms" which should look the same as "ozfitsports.com.au" which is where I copied the theme from.

I have spent 6hrs searching the web and can't seem to find anything that I havnet already done.

I woudl really appreciate any suggestions as to what I have done wrong or have missed.
I am using magento ce 1.6.1

Thanks

Comment: and I hope you are clearing the cache after making those config changes?

Comment: Check if you don't have design changes applied in time periods. You can do this in System > Design. Check if you don't have overriden pages theme individually.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that it might not be running the correct store.

To test this out go to a page in your original theme and `echo` out the store code to make sure.

Here is the code to test this:

```
$storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();  // Gets the current store's code

$storeName = Mage::app()->getStore()->getName();  // Gets the current store's name

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();  // Gets the current store's details

$store->getData();
```